# Add options to has_one association in subclass in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance

Is it possible to add options to a has_one association that is declared in a superclass, without loosing the options stated in the superclass? Something like this:

```
class AbstractBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  has_one :foo, dependent: :destroy
  // Shared validations and stuff for the :foo association
end

class BarA < AbstractBar
  // BarA should have association to FooA
  has_one :foo, class_name: foo_a
end

class BarB < AbstractBar
  // BarB should have association to FooB
  has_one :foo, class_name: foo_b
end
```

Above example will not work since the `dependent: :destroy` will be lost in the subclasses.

Comment: You could store the options in a hash and merge, or simply overwrite the destroy to call the destroy of the superclass. I guess.

Comment: @preciz How can I store the options in a hash? Could you give an example?

Comment: Turns out calling destroy of the superclass doesn't help. And I think merging is a bad absctraction pattern here. I guess you should be explicit about this in every subclass.

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking! Then I think I will omit the declaration in `AbstractBar` and let the subclasses declare the association to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible.
But foreign_key of foo in `BarA` is `bar_a_id` and foreign_key of foo in `BarB` is `bar_b_id`

Maybe `FooA` and `FooB` are subclasses of `Foo`.
So you should add foreign_key option like

```
has_one :foo, class_name: 'FooA', foreign_key: 'bar_id'
```

Comment: What about the `dependent: :destroy`?

Comment: @ehannes you should add destroy option in subclass too

Comment: Then the association in the superclass is useless, right? I am interested in adding options in a subclass, not redefine the whole association.

Comment: foo association is replaced in subclass. association name `foo` is kind of key in association store things...